# How to serialize object field in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have Profile model, which is auth model. And I have Blog model. I want to serialize model as it will give me `{author: {user_name:.., photo: photo_path}, blog_title:some_title, ..}`. Shortly, I want use author field as inner serialiser. I have already ProfileSerialiser and BlogSerializer. Here's my BlogList serializer:

```
class BlogListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = MiniProfileSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'like_count', 'author']
        read_only_fields = ['views', 'author', 'like_count']
```

And MiniProfileSerializer:

```
class MiniProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['user_name', 'image']
```

and view:

```
class BlogListAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = BlogListSerializer
    queryset = Blog.published.all()
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
```

Answer (score 0):

Django REST Framework does not support writing to a nested serializer out of the box. You can check out [DRF Writeable Nested](https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested), or write your own custom behavior on create by overwriting `create()` in the `BlogListSerializer`.

**EDIT**: Here's some more docs on the topic: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers